# Import-Module Posh-SSH > Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script using Posh-SSH. It works in PS5.1 but fails in PS7.41, producing the following error:

Import-Module: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'

I'm using Posh-SSH 3.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Updated to Posh-SSH to 3.1.3 fixed the issue